# Associating Lists With OOTB Workflows

Tags: workflow, approval-process

So I created a custom list and infopath form and published it to SharePoint. Then from that page I added a workflow and chose the globally reusable Approval workflow. Now I'm trying to edit the workflow in designer, but when I do a lookup for values in Current Item, it isn't showing any fields from the custom form I created.

Am I missing something big here? Why are my list fields not available in Current Item when the workflow should be associated?

Answer (score 0):

You need to promote the fields when publishing your infopath form

Comment: I do not understand how to do this. I've searched online for several hours for how to promote a field, all to no avail.